# Why do I get different accents?

Tags: verbatim, accents

```
1) \begin{ttfamily}\verb 'OR'1'='1 \end{ttfamily} 

2) \begin{ttfamily}\verb SELECT userid FROM CMSUsers WHERE user = 'foo' AND password = 'bar'; \end{ttfamily}
```

I'd like to have the accents like the ones I get in 1) also in 2)

I'm wondering, the code is the same but the results are different.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: 1. There is no `ttfamily` environment. 2. Use delimiters for the `\verb` macro: `\verb|'OR'1'='1|` and `\verb|SELECT userid FROM CMSUsers WHERE user = 'foo' AND password = 'bar';|`. 3. In these cases you could just use `\texttt`.

Comment: In its current shape, your question makes a little sense to me. Please, convert it to a [Minimal (non)-Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), and eventually add image of the desired output (printscreen from another program, ...).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

Only for T1 encoding you'll get the same. Otherwise some symbols are taken from the symbol font instead of the typewriter font:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\verb|foo "\bar" {baz} 'OR'1'='1'|

{\ttfamily foo "\textbackslash bar" \{baz\} 'OR'1'='1'}

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
\ttfamily foo "\textbackslash bar" \{baz\} 'OR'1'='1'

\fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont% Bera Mono, can be scaled \usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
foo "\textbackslash bar" \{baz\} 'OR'1'='1'
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone I found a solution by using \begin{ttfamily}\verb|...|\end{ttfamily}

Comment: sorry, but that solution is nonsense.